# Linux: find a match pattern and rename whole file with that Match

Tags: regex, rename

I have hundred of id file with format like this

```
106527-Sup, Perman  .jpg
106528-Iron, man  .jpg
106529-Bat, man  .jpg
106530-Spider, man  .jpg
```

I need to rename them to

```
106527.jpg
106528.jpg
106529.jpg
106530.jpg
```

How do I it with regex and rename command

Comment: Does `rename -n 's/^(\d+).*\.jpg$/$1/' *.jpg` work for you?

Comment: If Maroun's answer works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use perl-based `rename`:

```
rename 's/^(\d+).*jpg$/$1\.jpg/' *.jpg
```

- `^` matches the position at the beginning of the input
- `\d+` matches one or more digit
- `.*` matches everything in between
- `$` matches the position at the end of the input

The first group (`$1`) contains the digits you want to replace with.

Comment: Thank you,
Here's the result
106527
106528
106529
106530

It strip out .jpg

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much!